# Ruby Array Item Extract Specific Values

Tags: ruby

I have an array that includes a list of items that look like the following:

```
#<InvTypes typeID: 235, typeName: "That's the right stuff">, #<InvTypes typeID: 5, typeName: "And-some-of This">
```

How would I be able to extract the typeID and typeName?

I'm assuming I'd `array.each`, but I'm unsure from there what I'd do.

I'm .to_a the result. Without that though, the code looks like the following: `#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<InvTypes typeID: 18, typeName: "Stuff">, #<InvTypes typeID 19, typeName: "More Stuff's">, ...]>`

Comment: What do you mean by "id" or "name"?

Comment: It's encased in <'s so I need to get around the formatting. One second.

Comment: Are you sure your '`array`' isn't really a `hash`?

Comment: Well, I'm .to_a the result. Without that though, the code looks like the following: `#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<InvTypes typeID: 18, typeName: "Stuff">, #<InvTypes typeID 19, typeName: "More Stuff's">, ...]>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Pluck returns an Array of attribute values type-casted to match the
>   plucked column names, if they can be deduced. Plucking an SQL fragment
>   returns String values by default.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck

**SOLUTION**:

```
your_relation.pluck(:typeID, :typeName)
```